# Trying to access array offset on value of type null in laravel 10 when sending email

Tags: php, laravel, mailtrap

i'm using laravel 10 and livewire 3. i'm trying to send email using mailtrap and i'm working on my local machine now.
This is my livewire component

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Inbox;

use Livewire\Attributes\Title;
use Livewire\Attributes\Validate;
use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Mail\ComposeMail;

#[Title('Email Compose')]
class Compose extends Component
{
    #[Validate('required|email')]
    public $to;
    #[Validate('required|string|max:255')]
    public $subject;
    #[Validate('required|string')]
    public $message;

    public function send()
    {
        $this->validate();

        if(!is_null($this->to)){
            Mail::to($this->to)->send(new ComposeMail($this->subject, $this->message));
        }


        session()->flash('success', 'Mail sended successfully');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.inbox.compose');
    }
}
```

This is my laravel mailable

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Content;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Envelope;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Address;

class ComposeMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $subject;
    public $messages;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     */
    public function __construct($subject, $messages)
    {
        $this->subject = $subject;
        $this->messages = $this->sanitizeMessage($messages);
    }

    /**
     * Get the message envelope.
     */
    public function envelope(): Envelope
    {
        return new Envelope(
            from: new Address('john0@gmail.com', 'john'),
            subject: 'testing',
        );
    }
    
    /**
     * Get the message content definition.
     */
    public function content(): Content
    {
        return new Content(
            view: 'mails.send',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the attachments for the message.
     *
     * @return array<int, \Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Attachment>
     */
    public function attachments(): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    private function sanitizeMessage($message): string
    {
        return htmlentities($message);
    }
}
```

blade file

```
<h1>mail sent</h1>
```

.env file

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=6c9158bd41cb6e
MAIL_PASSWORD=********686d
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="john@gmail.com"
```

when i click on send button to send the email i get following error

```
ErrorException
PHP 8.2.12

10.43.0
Trying to access array offset on value of type null
and show the red at this code of line " Mail::to($this->to)->send(new ComposeMail($this->subject, $this->message));"
```

i'm tryng to send email in laravel 10 and livewire 3 using mailtrap but i'm geting an error. i'm expecting the solution of the error and the reason why this error occur.

Comment: i found the problem in my code. there was mailtrap credentials issue.

Comment: What was the issue in your credentials? I'm also having same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error is generally thrown on arrays, you should first check the type of $to variable. Most probably this must be coming as an array. On empty arrays if(!is_null($this->to) condition will not return false.

Comment: i checked, the $this->to coming as string not array

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed. You just need to focus on that config. That problem comes from that configuration. For example, the MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS should be the same as your domain, etc.

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=6c9158bd41cb6e
MAIL_PASSWORD=********686d
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="john@gmail.com"
```